# Cannot understand the error message from a illegal list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I know this list of tuples doesn't work because the elements of the tuples are not with the same type. But I couldn't understand the error message.

```
Prelude> [(1,2),("One",2)]

<interactive>:1:3: error:
    ? Could not deduce (Num [Char]) arising from the literal ‘1’
      from the context: Num b
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Num b => [([Char], b)]
        at <interactive>:1:1-17
    ? In the expression: 1
      In the expression: (1, 2)
      In the expression: [(1, 2), ("One", 2)]
```

Here I think `Num[Char])` represents "One". Then what does it means "arising from the literal ‘1’? Does it mean the type of the respective element in the same place has to be integer? And then again, what does it mean from the context: Num b? This make me very confused.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `[1, "One"]` already triggers the error.

Let's dissecting he error: the key point is

```
   Could not deduce (Num [Char]) arising from the literal ‘1’
```

This actually means "I need to use `1 :: [Char]`, since that's the only way the list could type check. However, I don't know how to interpret the literal 1 as a `[Char]`". (As a reminder, `[Char]` and `String` are exactly the same type, and both are the type of string literals such as `"One"`.)

Haskell is a bit peculiar in its handling of numeric literals like `1`. There are roughly treated as if the were `Integer`s, the arbitrary-precision integer type, and then immediately transformed into the wanted type using the method `fromInteger` of typeclass `Num`.

```
class Num a where
   fromInteger :: Integer -> a
   ...
```

In the standard libraries, this class has instances for all numeric types. The user can add others, e.g. for their user-defined numeric types.

A silly programmer could even add an instance for strings!

```
instance Num [Char] where
   fromInteger n = "urk!" ++ show n
```

This instance is bogus since it can't reasonably define the other methods, but in principle it could be used. With this instance in scope, the original code type checks!
We can test it in GHCi:

```
> [(1,2),("One",2)]
[("urk!1",2),("One",2)]
```

Note how Haskell converted the literal as we told it to do.

A a final warning: don't even think to add such an instance to a serious program :) The class `Num` should be used only for numeric types, and strings are not numeric.